# Use home as "Adjective" in the sentence

Tags: grammar

I am not sure about the meaning of the bold sentence below. What does it mean?

Choir singing is a popular pastime. In 2013, 32.5 million adults in the United States, roughly 10 percent of the population, sang in choirs, and **England is home to more than 3000 active choral groups**

Comment: **Home** in the sentence is indicating that it (literally) has more than 3000 active choral groups, kind of like how many of them are *in* England.

Answer (score 2):

> England is home to more than 3000 active choral groups

means the same as:

> More than 3000 active choral groups ar located in England.

The word "home" here is not an adjective, but a noun in this usage.